# Need help understanding why question is "too broad"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553515/cant-serve-static-file-in-wwwroot-directory-under-net-core-2) has been closed as "too broad" and as far I can imagine, it's because there's no question that's quickly obtainable to it (hence implying that the information provided is too scarce).

How can I improve the question at this point?

I can't provide more information because I don't possess any and I'm getting nothing more as feedback than what I've already mentioned in it.

I need to be humble and wonder if my question perhaps isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow. It seems to me that I got a link to a quick-fix at first and when that turned out not to be useful (the user commenting hasn't read the question properly, simply assuming that it's one of the default oopsies), the question was "too broad".

The way I figure, if it's not "too broad" then it's already answered and, hence a dupe. But if it's not a dupe, then it's too broad. Somehow, I feel that there should be a middle ground when it's neither - how can I improve my formulation to reach there, please?

Comment: Too broad is definitely the wrong close reason. I don't have domain knowledge but I can imagine you could be a little more specific about how you test things and conclude that things aren't working. Some basic HTTP request/response logging for example.

Comment: Is the code you posted **all** the code that's necessary for anyone else to reproduce the issue? Is the process you described every step of the entire process required to reproduce the issue? (I don't know anything about ASP.NET) If not, you should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The "too broad" doesn't seem very helpful / appropriate here - it should've been the MCVE reason.

Comment: It is a "it doesn't work" question with no obvious leads to formulate an answer.  SO users could only guess at things you already double-checked ten times yourself, you are not going to be happy when they do.  Ask a friend or team member to look over your shoulder or do the exact same thing you did, the missing detail might well pop out.

Comment: It's not "too broad" however it's still not a usable question. You have posted the software equivalent of "my car doesn't work" and the only tests you've done are "make sure it's a car". 404 is "Not Found"
and you have not shown any effort to find the cause of the problem or verify where the server is looking or verify that the file(s) are actually there and the server process has rights to them.

Comment: I think its a valid question, its just that you are quite **unlucky** because there are users here in SO that did not receive your question well, thus the close.

Comment: @Mr.J The other comments are very valid, but I have been the victim of this on several occasions, and I wish there were a way to mitigate it.

Comment: The "too broad" close button text starts "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer." That agrees with the comments here, including the body of comments that start by saying (incorrectly) that it's not too broad.

Comment: @jsejcksn there are users here in SO that seems to look at themselves as "gods of justice" so they smite those questions that they can't answer.

Comment: I have been bitten by this many times. Someone comes, does not read the question carefully, and closes the question as "too broad" or "duplicate". What can be done to minimize this kind of incidents? The system should make sure that the close-voter has paid due attention to the question and isn't just close-vote-trigger-happy.

Comment: It is not too broad.  You took a large number of steps to attempt to narrow the field. The close voters will justify their poor choice in why they closed it with another option that they didn't chose.  That said, it does seem like a fishing question, in the sense that there is not a specific error to repair beyond "it doesn't work".  Some people hate those kind of questions, because they require experience and good guesswork; so they close it based on whatever justification they can cook up (then they defend their choice or say it wasn't the real reason).

Comment: @LoneLearner, no single ordinary user can close a question as "too broad", no matter their rep or badges.  It takes five close votes.  Duplicates are a different matter, but not relevant here.

Comment: @Mr.J I will close a question regardless of whether I can or can't answer it, if it doesn't mean our site's requirements. There is no rule or need to be capable of answering a question in order to close it.

Comment: ... nor that me being able to answer a question means it should remain open.

Comment: @Mr.J Please provide data backing your claim. Because assuming malice is counter to our "Be Nice" policy.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan this question is my data to back up my claim, good thing it has been opened by users here.

Comment: @mason I understand your point, I too close questions if they are completely broad (e.g posting codes only without any clues as to what the problem is, or what does he want to happen) but these kinds of question are not broad, they are unanswerable if you may because they are mostly customized questions, questions which needs the complete code for us to replicate.

Comment: @Mr.J If we need the complete code to answer it, it's too broad. They didn't follow the "Minimal" in [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think it's naive to believe that people actually read and consider the reason behind closing a question. I know quite a few members who will pick "which ever freaking thing dude before me picked" and, also, those who click to close the question because it's already got a vote or two to close. It should work the way you figure but, in my experience, it doesn't.

Comment: @mason Without going into details and specific questions - how can one be certain **for every case** that it's too broad if one isn't knowledgeable on the subject? I imagine the cases where it's your ignorance that mislead you to believe that a question is poorly formulated whereas it actually is a bit above your comprehension. (NB. By no means do I imply that such is valid for **every nor many** questions, because some are just plainly terrible. However, it strikes me as arrogant not to consider that it's not the question but rather that it might be you...)

Comment: @DonkeyBanana I never said "every case". Sure, I've never programmed at C++ in my life, so there's a lot of C++ questions I shouldn't vote on. But if I see a question tagged as C++ and it's asking how to write an entire application, I can certainly vote to close as Too Broad without needing to know anything about the language. You just have to leave it up to the judgement of the reviewer. The point I'm trying to make here is that you merely need to have enough knowledge to tell if it doesn't meet the site's requirements.

Comment: @mason I disagree with that stance. Example: *how to create an entire Angular application with implemented routing?* can be answered by *add --no-testing to ng new Plopp*. However, if one hasn't worked with CLI for Angular, the answer will be humongous and definitely too broad. But one won't realize it. I'm not assessing **you** - I just miss the humbleness of competence (believing that one knows enough to pass judgement). I'm going to drop the subject now because my experience tells me that this might get very infected. Please don't take me not replying as ignoring you.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana When I said "create an application" as an example of too broad of a question I didn't mean "do the base scaffolding". We often see questions like "I need to create an application that does X, Y, and Z" and it can be clearly seen, even with little domain experience, that it's too broad. This has nothing to do with humbleness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), these two criteria define a question that is "too broad":

> if your question could be answered by an entire book

(IMO, this criteria should be modified because any question, *could* be answered by an entire book, but) an entire book is not *necessary* to answer this one.

> or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct)

OP will definitely be able to determine a correct answer via error-free runtime.

**Therefore, the question is not "too broad".**